# python: is there a version of functools.wraps that preserves mypy --strict?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Lets say I have:

```
def foo(arg: int, arg2: str, arg3: int) -> MyReturnType:
```

this variant preserves mypy types, as in mypy knows the types of `safefoo`:

```
safefoo = functools.partial(foo, arg2="whatever")
```

however, this does not:

```
def safefoo(*args, **kwargs):
    # maybe i wanna do other stuff here
    return foo(*args, arg2="whatever", **kwargs)
```

Nor does this:

```
 from functools import wraps

 @wraps(foo)
 def safefoo(*args, **kwargs):
    return foo(*args, arg2="whatever", **kwargs)
```

In both of these, mypy still complains `safefoo` is untyped and called in a typed context:  `Call to untyped function "safefoo" in typed context`

how do I wrap in a way that makes mypy happy? (without redefining the types)

Comment: Could you specify what it is about `wraps` that doesn't currently work for you? I think that might make your question a little easier to understand.

Comment: @CrazyChucky edited for clarity

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand... `wraps` wouldn't be for decorating the original `foo`, if you were to use it. You'd decorate `safefoo` with `@wraps(foo)`.

Comment: @CrazyChucky I tried using functools.wraps but I am still getting mypy to complain, edited again. rather than comments can you please post an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure that what you want is possible... How is mypy supposed to know that **kwargs from safefoo doesn't also include "arg2"? If it cannot know that, it cannot properly statically type this. You would have to typehint "same as kwargs of foo but without arg2" which would be quite complex. For cases where you don't introduce another arg, i would make safefoo a decorator and use ParamSpec to pass through the *args **kwargs types.